Show that $\mathcal{S}_{s\delta }$ is closed with respect to finite unions
Let $X$ be a set $\mathcal{S}\subseteq 2^X$ be a collection of subsets of $X$. Denote by $\mathcal{S}_s$ and $\mathcal{S}_\delta$ the collections of all finite union and countable intersection of elements of $\mathcal{S}$, respectively. Define $\mathcal{S}_{s\delta }:=(\mathcal{S}_s)_{\delta}$. How can I show that $\mathcal{S}_{s\delta }$ is closed with respect to finite unions?
This property is stated in the proof of the 1.12.4. Proposition of the book "Measure Theory" by V.I. Bogachev.

What I tried to do:
Let $\{S_i\}_{i=0}^n\subseteq \mathcal{S}_{s\delta}$ be any finite subset.
From the definition of $\mathcal{S}_{s\delta}$ we know that for all $i\in \{0,\cdots,n\}$ there's a subset $\{S_{i,j}\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq \mathcal{S}\!_s$ such that $S_i=\cap _{j\in\mathbb{N}}\!\,S_{i,j}$. Also, for any $i\in\{0,\cdots,n\}$ and $j\in\mathbb{N}$ there're $k_{i,j}\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\{S_{i,j,k}\}_{k=0}^{k_{i,j}}\subseteq \mathcal{S}$ such that $S_{i,j}=\cup _{k=0}^{k_{i,j}}\!\,S_{i,j,k}$.Therefore,
$$\cup _{i=0}^n\!\,S_i=\cup _{i=0}^n\!\,\cap _{j\in\mathbb{N}}\!\,\cup _{k=0}^{k_{i,j}}\!\,S_{i,j,k}\,\,\color{red}{(1)}$$
For all $i\in \{0,\cdots,n\}$, define
$$\mathcal{F}\!_i:=\big\{f\in (\cup _{j\in \mathbb{N}}\!\,\{0,\cdots,k_{i,j}\})^\mathbb{N}:(\forall j\in\mathbb{N})\big(f(j)\in \{0,\cdots,k_{i,j}\}\big)\big\}$$
Using (1) and the fact that the power set lattice $(2^X,\subseteq )$ is a completely distributive lattice (see this link), we can conclude that
$$\cup _{i=0}^n\!\,S_{i}=\cup _{i=0}^n\!\,\cup _{f\in \mathcal{F}\!_i}\cap _{j\in\mathbb{N}}S_{i,j,f(i)}$$
I tried to simply the RHS of the previous equality to use again the fact that $(2^X,\subseteq )$ is a completely distributive lattice, but I failed.

Generally it's sufficient to show $\mathcal S_{s\delta}$ is closed under pairwise union. From this, a simple inductive argument gives arbitrary finite unions. You can apply the following claim to complete your problem.
Claim. If $\mathcal S$ is closed under pairwise union, then $\mathcal S_\delta$ is closed under pairwise union.
Proof. Suppose $A,B\in \mathcal S_\delta$, so $A=\bigcap_{i\geq 1}A_i$ and $B=\bigcap_{j\geq 1}B_j$. Then
$$
A\cup B=\bigcap_{i\geq 1}(A_i\cup B)=\bigcap_{i\geq 1}\bigcap_{j\geq 1}(A_i\cup B_j)
$$
But $A_i,B_j\in \mathcal S$, so $A_i\cup B_j\in \mathcal S$ and thus $A\cup B$ is a countable intersection of elements of $\mathcal S$. This means  $A\cup B\in \mathcal S_\delta$.
